# Object property value as type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I have an object, for instance:

```
const Colors = {
  blueish: "#0070C1",
  grayish: "#d6d6d6"
}
```

How do I tell typescript "I want to allow any of the Color's object properties to be passed", for instance if I'm making an Icon component:

```
const Icon = ({fill}: {fill: Colors (compiler complains here))}) => <svg><path fill={fill}/></svg>
```

Note, I do not want to say fill can be `fill: Colors.blueish | Colors.grayish` because I want to allow any color in future added to my Colors object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `Colors` object immutable, otherwise TS will infer color value as a `string` instead `"#0070C1" | "#d6d6d6"`.

```js
import React from 'react'

const Colors = {
    blueish: "#0070C1",
    grayish: "#d6d6d6"
} as const;

// returns union of all values
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

const Icon = <T extends Values<typeof Colors>>({ fill }: { fill: T }) => <svg><path fill={fill} /></svg>

const y = <Icon fill="#0070C1" /> // ok
const x = <Icon fill="#0070C2" /> // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gGEIAbaGuAXjgG9S4%204ARkwCuSYDQAWALjgAiAMQAGRQHZF9AIyyANL34BzKCgCe46XPkATAGw2bs0gF84KNpVowA3ORjGwSOAA1FBEkGgAeABUAPg44SIBtAGskYwhMeIBdcnc6OABJdziouCQADxgkKks2YNCI3390uEYWKBpo6IAKLjhMYCYmOEcZXv7BmUjhgEoOWPCaADd9aPCwFBgJPoGmdi5xpmcAelWjpZWc6jzjYsLqbcH2BWU1TVk4E4%20juAgkiiv4GVbkUDk8lKp1AAmd6fI7fcr%20DBISylKA4KDkIA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'keyof' of operator for that.

```
const Icon = ({fill}: {fill: keyof typeof Colors}) => <svg><path fill={fill}/></svg>
```

Comment: No, in that case the type will get evaluated to property names, i.e. `blueish | grayish` instead of to their actual hex values.

Comment: Yes, did not ready question completly . Then @captain-yossarian answer should fix your problem